# Retrieve location lat/long (CLLocationCoordinate2d) from Calendar event (EKCalendarItem / EKEvent)

Tags: calendar, location, ios8, ekevent, cllocationcoordinate2d

The `EKCalendarItem` has the property "Location", but it is a `NSString`.
New iOS8 functionality shows a nice map for an event, so there must be a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` attached to the `EKCalendarItem`, correct?
Where can I find this `CLLocationCoordinate2D`?

Comment: There is nothing new i see in eventkit framework

Comment: Thanks Bhumit, the map location coordinate is clearly connected to the event, so I wonder where it is stored?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this should get what you need:

```
for (EKEvent *calEvent in self.allMyEvents) {

   EKStructuredLocation *location = (EKStructuredLocation *)[calEvent valueForKey:@"structuredLocation"];

   if (location) {

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`EKCalendarItem` does not contain any CLLocationCoordinate2D property it has `location` which is `NSString` as you mentioned in your question.

You can use `location` property to get co-ordinates. You can get the coordinates from a string using `CoreLocation` framework's  `CLGeocoder` .

You can use this code.

```
 CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geocoder geocodeAddressString:locationString completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    if([placemarks count]) {
        CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
        CLLocation *location = placemark.location;
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = location.coordinate;
        NSLog(@"coordinate = (%f, %f)", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude);

    }
}];
```

Here `locationString` is the location string retrieved from `EKCalendarItem` 's location property. The default iCal app must be doing something similar, Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks Bhumit. Yes, I use this in a few of my apps but the [placemarks objectAtIndex:0]; will not always be the correct location.         I think the location is stored in EKStructuredLocation  https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKStructuredLocationClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/EKStructuredLocation just have to do some tests to find out how to get to it....

Comment: `EKStructuredLocation`  is the property of  `EKAlarm` So i doubt it is being used for Calendar item, Anyways ill look around hoping we get a better way to achieve this

Comment: Found it!     NSArray *eventList = [self.eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:fetchCalendarEvents]; for(int i=0; i < eventList.count; i++){ NSLog(@"Event Title:%@", [[eventList objectAtIndex:i] title]); NSLog (@"Event location:%@", [[eventList objectAtIndex:i] structuredLocation]); }

Comment: IS it working? i still dont understand how did you use  `structuredLocation` for `EKEvent`

Comment: @property(copy, nonatomic) EKStructuredLocation *structuredLocation; private in parent EKCalendarItem  so have to parse the [EKEvent description]. Hope this will be made public soon.... https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EKCalendarItem.h